# Will this TVS protect my LED from inductor voltage surge?

Tags: led, protection, tvs

Say I have an illuminated switch (say, [this](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07ZB2GDL4), or something equivalent) hooked up like so:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fxCT1O.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

(Presumed internal resistor of the switch's LED not shown. Circuit is simplified compared to actual application. In case the link isn't working or you don't want to look at Amazon stuff, the switch is a 12V common "vandal" momentary switch with red illuminated ring, like you might see used as a personal computer power button.)

The TVS is a [SA18CA](https://www.littelfuse.com/products/tvs-diodes/leaded/sa.aspx), V<sub>clamp</sub> ≈ 30V.

At some point, I had an additional diode (1N4007) in here intended to protect the LED from the voltage spike from the electromagnet inductor(s) (12V, nominal combined continuous current ~1A or less), but I realized I wasn't convinced it was doing anything.

In a circuit resembling the one shown, **do I need any additional protection for the LED**, or is a TVS (as shown) sufficient? (Keeping in mind I don't have a data sheet for the LED and so am just guessing at its characteristics. [This forum thread](https://www.eevblog.com/forum/beginners/what-is-the-reverse-breakdown-voltage-of-a-red-or-green-5-mm-led/) suggests a good chance it can take a pretty high voltage. Also, I would guess that the LED has an internal resistor dropping its voltage from 12V to <3V, which would imply that the voltage I can safely apply to the *switch* is likely much higher than without the resistor.)

If just the TVS is okay, how high could I reasonably push V<sub>clamp</sub> if the LED is the only thing that needs protection? (IIRC, higher V<sub>clamp</sub> ⇒ faster collapse of the magnetic field, which is desirable for my application. Practically speaking, I'll probably need to limit V<sub>clamp</sub> for the sake of other components.)

If I definitely need additional protection, what and where? (Will a 1N4007 *in series* with the LED suffice? Note that a reverse parallel diode *defeats the purpose of the TVS* and is not desirable.)

Comment: As shown, if you close the switch you will quickly blow up the LED.  If it didn't blow up the LED, the reverse 30V developed across it due to the inductor when you open the switch would probably finish the job.

Comment: Many misconceptions. V_clamp should be as low as possible but safely above your 12 V supply. You said nothing about the inductor specs. Large coils can kill both the TVS and LED easily. Where is your 1N4007 here? That woukd help too, could even solve the problem alone - the TVS as shown may be useless at all.

Comment: @datenheim, for protecting *components*, yes. Am I wrong that allowing higher voltage collapses the magnetic field faster? As to the 1N4007, the question is *do I need it* (or more than one, and if so, where)? As to the inductors (plural, actually), what's "large"? I don't know Henry ratings. I know alleged total current is ~150ma, although reviews suggest that ~300mA may be more accurate.

Comment: @JohnD, why? The LED takes 12V. Also, the cited thread suggests that some LEDs might happily shrug off 30V reverse voltage.

Comment: @Matthew LEDs don't take 12V, but if it's an LED circuit with integrated current limiting it might be OK in the forward direction. (I just saw your note about the resistor not being shown which I may have missed originally.)  If it's not specified for 30V in reverse it MIGHT work or it might work for some period of time, or it might be damaged immediately.  No way to know for sure.

Comment: @JohnD, I'd be fairly surprised if there isn't just a resistor tucked into the switch (i.e. the package, not the logical component) somewhere. Is that going to help with how much reverse voltage the LED sees? If not (or if it won't help *enough*), do I just need to protect the LED from *any* reverse voltage, which presumably a 1N4007 can do? I think I smell an Answer...

Comment: What would the TVS protect if it is a 30V TVS? It will just allow 30V in reverse over the LED. The LED would still be experiencing 30V in reverse, instead of higher voltage. And why do you say the diode in parallel would defeat the TVS? It willl just protect the LED better.

Comment: @Justme, yes, I think you see the question; is the LED likely to survive 30V backwards? This is very unclear, as the "official" ratings for most LEDs are apparently extremely conservative. Why not a reverse parallel diode? Because it would become a flyback diode over the inductor and would make the TVS unnecessary. As noted, the reason I'm using a TVS instead of said flyback is to allow the magnetic field to collapse faster.